# undefined index error in mysql xampp

Tags: php

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM p_u_r WHERE p_name = '$d'");
        $S=$row['id'];

         if(mysql_num_rows($result1) == 0) {


      row not found, do stuff...
}
```

this code send an error of undefined index error. I have created p_u_r table in my database but no data is inserted.

Comment: *"undefined index error"* - That could be *anything*. I've no idea what this question is about. You're behind your computer; we're not. Show your full and actual code.

Comment: You need to fetch something to make a row e.g. `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result1);` Then, if you have no data in the table, `$row['id']` will be undefined. Looks like you have some more work to do on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM p_u_r WHERE p_name = '$d'");
        $S=$row['id'];

         if(mysql_num_rows($result1) == 0) {


      row not found, do stuff...
}
```

It is likely because `$row`... doesn't exist. You should write something like that:

```
// assuming you have created $d already...
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM p_u_r WHERE p_name = '$d'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result1) == 0) {


    //  row not found, do stuff...
} 
else {   
//fetch your results using mysql_fetch_assoc() or mysql_fetch_row()         
//...

 }
```

BTW Do you know using MySQL extension is DEPRECATED and you should create code using MySQLi ?